# MultiAutoCompleteTextView doesn't accept blank spaces

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

My problem is that when I suggest sentences in `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, when I press spacebar, the suggestions disappear.
Example:

*Suggested words:*

> THE ROCK
>  THE BALL
>  THERMAL

If I write "THE", all sentences are displayed, but if I write "THE " (with blank space) the suggestions are dismissed. 
I want that if you write "THE ", the elements "THE ROCK" and "THE BALL" are displayed in suggested words.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer` and create a spaceTokenizer as below. Then set `multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());`

```
public class SpaceTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor;

    while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
        i--;
    }
    while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}

public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor;
    int len = text.length();

    while (i < len) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            return i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return len;
}

public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
    int i = text.length();

    while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        i--;
    }

    if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        return text;
    } else {
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                    Object.class, sp, 0);
            return sp;
        } else {
            return text + " ";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I already have a `CustomTokenizer`, and doesn't work. Your `Tokenizer` doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OrsN2xRpDmA 
>   I just ran into a similar problem and wrote a simple multi word derivation. It defaults to a "," separator but you can set it whatever you like using the "setSeparator" method.
>   **or**
>   this stack-overflow answer might be helpful cause it experiences the same problem:
>   [AutoCompleteTextView backed by CursorLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12854336/7012517)